# Is there a way on OS X just like SHSetLocalizedName() on Windows OS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, desktop.ini

I really want to make a directory to have another localized or customized name. In the other word, the directory has two name. The one is a name to be showed to user, the other is a name which is a real name used by a filesystem. It just like a **SHSetLocalizedName** function supported by Windows OS.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please reward the people who have helped you and [accept answers to your older questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks.

Comment: I really want to do that. Could you inform me how to reward a person who helps me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions can be found on the Apple developer pages, search for "localized folder name" ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingPathnames.html)).